# Peek lock multiple messages from service bus topic

Tags: azure, httprequest, azure-logic-apps

How to read multiple messages from a service bus topic subscription under peek lock with http request not via service bus connector and using managed identity authentication?

Comment: By HTTP request you mean REST API. Correct? Is there a reason for using REST API?

Comment: Yes REST API and Its a requirement to use managed identity authentication only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using REST API, it is not possible to get multiple messages in a single request. The REST API operation is [`Peek-Lock Message`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/peek-lock-message-non-destructive-read) which only returns a single message.

If you have to fetch multiple messages, either call this operation multiple times on a topic subscription or make use of AMQP which supports fetching multiple messages.